# Vue and Vuex state checking

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I am experimenting with Vue and VueX and while everything is working well, there is one aspect that is troubling with regards to the store mechanism.

I have a component that loads a set of data from a remote service via axios. It works correctly and is called when the component is created.

```
export default {
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('foo/getBar');
  }
  ...
}
```

This correctly populates the "bar" variable in the component with the valeus returned from the api call.

When I next view the component in the application, the created function is called again and the api called again, which returns the same data.

What is the best practice way of avoiding subsequent calls until we know that there is different data to be collected? Or more precisely, how do I invalidate data in the store when necessary so that api call is made only when it needs it?

Answer (score 0):

You can put your api call to the parent or root component then place a refresh button to the child component.

Or you can check if variable `bar` is empty then make the api call.

Comment: The second option is what I am currently doing. I just wasn't sure if there was anything built into vuex that would accomplish the same thing.

Comment: atm, there is no builtin solution to this in vuex. What we usually do is: if the data we are fetching is fixed or don't change from time to time, we make the api call in the parent component. Also we use GraphQL subscriptions to do this kind of stuff.